# How to delete a pointer inside a struct object when the struct object goes out of scope?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, memory-leaks

I have a struct object that contains a pointer to an object.

```
struct Track
{
    KalmanFilter* kalmanFilter; //Kalman filter for this track
    ....
};
```

I instantiate the struct and pointer objects by

```
Track track;
track.kalmanFilter = new KalmanFilter(contours[contour].centroid);
....
```

I then check each frame if the track is still valid by

```
//Temporary vector to hold alive tracks
std::vector<Track> tempTracks;

for(...)
{
    //If track is valid save into temp tracks
    if(tracks[track].deadTime <= deadTime) tempTracks.push_back(tracks[track]);
}

//Save all temp tracks back into tracks - this removes dead tracks that were in tracks
tracks = tempTracks;
```

After a while the micro-controller i'm using runs out of memory, this is the only pointer in my code so i'm pretty sure the KalmanFilter pointer is not being deleted.

So far I have tried a destructor in the Track struct which causes my micro-controller to hard fault immediately.

```
//Destructor frees up Kalman filter memory when the Track object goes out of scope
~Track()
{
    if(kalmanFilter) delete kalmanFilter;
}
```

and I have tried using a unique_ptr but I cannot get the code to compile, all the examples I have found instantiate the object being pointed to at the same time as instantiating the unique_ptr. In my case I don't think I can do this.

What is the correct way to handle a situation like this?

Thanks

EDIT

So based on the comments there seems to be two main points.

**Allocate the memory in the constructor**

I have rewritten my struct to be

```
struct Track
{
    Track(const Point& initialPosition) : kalmanFilter(initialPosition) {}
    ~Track() {}
    KalmanFilter kalmanFilter; //Kalman filter for this track
};
```

and I instantiate it by

```
Track track(contours[contour].centroid);
```

Is this correct?

**Find a better way to delete the tracks**

What is the best way to remove an object from a vector without messing up the indexing during the loop? Using an STL iterator?

I implemented the solution from @M.M that seems to work

```
tracks.erase(std::remove_if(tracks.begin(), tracks.end(), [&](Track const &t){return t.deadTime > deadTime;}));
```

Comment: [Did you follow the rule of three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)?

Comment: DR; TL; You have to delete allocated memory before the object gets out of scope.

Comment: @101010 yes I can do this manually but I was hoping there was some automatic way of doing it. Either a deconstructor that works or a unique_ptr

Comment: You should actually follow @NathanOliver's advice. Don't manage memory allocation outside of a `struct`, even better encapsulate such behavior interned with a class, and don't leave it publicly. Even more better, use a standard c++ container or smart pointer, and leave memory de-/allocation to this member.

Comment: "all the examples I have found instantiate the object being pointed to at the same time as instantiating the unique_ptr." unique_ptrs can be assigned to if the right hand side is an r-value: `myptr = std::make_unique<KalmanFilter>(contours[contour].centroid);` this automatically deletes the previous contents of the unique pointer.

Comment: Is there a case where `kalmanFilter` is not initialized? I noticed you initialize it after defining the object instead of in the constructor. It might have an undefined value that is not NULL and you try to delete it.

Comment: At first glance, besides that you should allocate the memory in the constructor. IMHO you need a `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Actually, I didn't notice you were copying them around. You are probably getting a double free somewhere.

Comment: You don't need to check for `nullptr` before calling delete.  Like `free`, it will do that check internally.

Comment: Re making a `unique_ptr` without constructing it: it is possible. You can simply have `std::unique_ptr<int> n; n = std::make_unique<int>(3);` See this example: https://ideone.com/WjJLdo

Comment: Another solution is to have `Track` can contain a member `KalmanFilter kalmanFilter;` .  The viability of this depends on the details of the KalmanFilter class.

Comment: Do note that checking the argument to `free` or `delete` for being zero/null is **always unnecessary**. Don't do it, there's no point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a smart pointer:

```
struct Track
{
    std::unique_ptr<KalmanFilter> kalmanFilter;
....
};
```

This means that when the `Track` is destroyed, if the smart pointer is managing a pointer it will invoke `delete` on that pointer.

It could be assigned by:

```
track.kalmanFilter.reset(new KalmanFilter(contours[contour].centroid));
```

although it'd be preferable to have this done by the constructor of `Track`.

---

This change will render `Track` non-copyable (but still movable). This is a good thing because previously your code did not behave properly on being copied anyway, so now the compiler will catch it for you.

You will need to modify your erase-loop to stop making copies of the elements. The normal way to do this is to use `vector::erase` combined with `std::remove_if` (the latter moves the selected elements to the end, and `erase` erases elements off the end):

```
tracks.erase( std::remove_if( begin(tracks), end(tracks), 
    [&](Track const &t) { return t.deadTime > deadTime; } ), end(tracks) );
```

Required includes would be `<memory>` and `<algorithm>`.

Comment: Thanks for answer, can you explain the last bit in more detail? Will that code remove tracks with a deadtime of <= deadtime or tracks with a deadtime of > deadtime?

Comment: The former. The function should return `true` for items to be removed, and `false` otherwise. I'll edit

Comment: OK thanks, I was comparing your solution to the wikipedia entry "v.erase( std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), is_odd), v.end() );" Why does your solution no require v.end() after the function?

Comment: tracks.end() is needed as last parameter to tracks.erase(), otherwise only one element will be removed. @JosephRoberts did you verify that?

Comment: Thanks @A.S.H good to know. I didn't test properly yet, I need to check it gives me the behavior I want and play around with the tracks.erase function if not. Instantiating the Kalman filter in the tracks constructor does however definitely work.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are eliminating dead tracks will cause many copies of each track to be made.

The destructor to one of your many copies will try to deallocate that memory while active copies are still using that kalman filter which can cause issues. Also, if you can't guarantee it is NULL before being assigned... could be a random pointer being deleted.

In this situation I'd use a shared pointer. But to be honest, I feel like there is a better overall structure for how you are storing/using the tracks, I'd have to think about it and know more about the implementation though.

Answer (score -1):

When you do push_back() you are creating a copy of the original Track object. Both the copy and the original object point to the same memory, and both at some point get destructed resulting in a double deallocation of the same address. Following the suggestions in the comments on better code organization will help avoid such bugs.

Comment: It'd be good to make your answer include suggestions, instead of directing people to comments (which may be deleted later, and shouldn't really include answers anyway). You can credit the comment author by mentioning their name if you like.